# Unexpected non-void return value in void function in request to server iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, methods, request, swift3

I try to make method for request to server contain Background and Main queue. Finally this method should return `NSDictionary` of my response from the server.

```
func sendRequest(UrlString urlString:String,MethodString method:String)->(NSDictionary)  {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = method
        //let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
        //request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            do {
                let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject] as NSDictionary

                return jsonDictionary

            } catch {
                //Handle the error
            }

            //return airports
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And now when try to return `jsonDictionary` in the main queue, it shows me this error:

> Unexpected non-void return value in void function

And now I don't know how to fix this problem.
I am using `Xcode 8`, `iOS8` and `Swift 3`.
Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have implemented at least two async operations and they are can't return values. For async operations you should use completion handlers like this:

```
func sendRequest(urlString: String, method: String, completion: @escaping (_ dictionary: NSDictionary?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string:urlString)!)
        request.httpMethod = method
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                // make error here and then
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                do {
                    let jsonDictionary:NSDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: Any] as NSDictionary

                    completion(jsonDictionary, nil)

                } catch {
                    completion(nil, error)
                }
            }

        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: With this working function, how you call it ? I understand urlString and method so for completion I have no idea, thank you for example and explanation.

Comment: it can be called like this:
`sendRequest(urlString: "http://localhost", method: "GET") { dictionary, error in
}`

Comment: I need another detail please, I call it: sendRequest(urlString: "https://localhost/signup.php", method: "POST") { dictionary, error in }. The data is correctly transmit to my php. When answer comming back to iOS I receive :
responseString : "{\\\"exception\\\":false,\\\"success\\\":false,\\\"status\\\":-9,\\\"message\\\":\\\"This username already exist !\\\"}\"")
CATCH ERROR ! Why answer not going to jsonDictionary ??

Comment: You need to replace `let responseString = ...` with serialization to JSON:
`let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String: Any]`

Comment: Why I need to serialisation responseString ? The next step is do it for this ? My app enter into DispatchQueue.main.async an start. The let jsonDictionary is catch an error. My log: responseString: ("\"{\\\"exception\\\":false,\\\"success\\\":true,\\\"status\\\":0,\\\"message\\\":\\\"Welcome KD!\\\"}\"")!
DispatchQueue.main.async
enter do
CATCH ERROR !
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}